# Simple AJAX in Form for ASP Classic and MS SQL Database

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, ajax, asp-classic

I have a every simple and small ms sql table called `Tbltest`

I have the following fields:

```
MAINID
NAME
ADDRESS
ADDRESS2
DEL_STATE
ZIPCODE
TELEPHONE
FAX
```

What I would like to do is: enter the `NAME` in a text input box and as I enter 4+ characters it will search the database to see if that `NAME` exists
if it does then it would get the `NAME, ADDRESS, ADDRESS2, DEL_STATE, ZIPCODE, TELEPHONE, FAX` and place them in their own input textbox.

I would also like to have it show a dropdown menu of some kind so if there are more then one name for example if there are 2+ or more `NAMES` as: *john* or *Bob*, etc...
then the user would pick one based on their `CITY` AND `STATE`.

**THE HTML FORM WOULD LOOK LIKE THIS:**

```
NAME:      [            ]  <-- as the user enters the name (in this input textbox) and if it exists the below would auto fill up/show

    Address:   [            ]  <-- This is a input textbox
    City:      [            ]  <-- This is a input textbox
    State:     [            ]  <-- This is a input textbox
    Zip:       [            ]  <-- This is a input textbox

    Telephone: [            ]  <-- This is a input textbox
    Fax:       [            ]  <-- This is a input textbox

    ID:        [            ]  <-- This is a hidden input textbox       

    { CONTINUE } <-- This is a button
```

So the only option is to use AJAX but I cannot find any simple examples for MS SQL and ASP Classic, let alone ones that have a dropdown for multi-results.
PLEASE HELP... Thanks

Comment: I think I found it, something like here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp

Comment: You'll probably want to use something like autocomplete for your selectable match list ( http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ ) and then have a 2nd call for when a user selects a match to retrieve your full data set for control pre-population. So you'll need at least your current presentation page and then a 2nd .asp page that will handle your database call and return your data back to the presentation page. The w3schools example was returning full HTML markup but your server page should probably just return data formatted as JSON or some other custom parsable string to handle the control prepop.